# How to write a generic function to evaluate column values inside withcolumn of spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, match, case

Hi I have the below dataframe which has countries column along with multiple other columns and more than a lack rows.I want to write a generic function(because used in multiple places) which can  be used inside the withcolumn to create a new column.

**input**

```
| countries  |
|------------|
| RFRA       | 
| BRES       |
| EAST       |
| RUSS       |
| ....       |
```

**output**

```
| countries |
|-----------|
| FRA       | 
| BRA       |
| POL       |
| RUS       |
| ...       |
```

Below is my code when I pass countries column to the function,am not able to evaluate the column with string. How can I extract the value from the column and evaluate with the string value specified and I want to return as a column.

```
val df = sample.withColumn("renamedcountries", replace($"countries"))

def replace(countries: Column) :Column = {
  val Updated = countries match {
    case "RFRA" => "FRA"
    case "BRES" => "BRA"
    case "RESP" => "ESP"
    case "RBEL" => "BEL"
    case "RGRB" => "GBR"
    case "RALL" => "DEU"
    case "MARO" => "MAR"
    case "RPOR" => "PRT"
    case _ => "unknown"
  }
  Updated
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the function logic you have as `udf` and call this `udf` from various places from code.

```
   import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

   val df = Seq( ("RFRA"), ("BRES"), ("RUSS")).toDF("countries")

   val mapCountries = udf[String, String](country => {
      val Updated = country match {
        case "RFRA" => "FRA"
        case "BRES" => "BRA"
        case "RESP" => "ESP"
        case "RBEL" => "BEL"
        case "RGRB" => "GBR"
        case "RALL" => "DEU"
        case "MARO" => "MAR"
        case "RPOR" => "PRT"
        case _ => "unknown"
      }
    Updated
   })

   df.withColumn("renamedCountries", mapCountries($"countries")).show()
  
+---------+----------------+
|countries|renamedCountries|
+---------+----------------+
|     RFRA|             FRA|
|     BRES|             BRA|
|     RUSS|         unknown|
+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Hi suresiva if i have more than one column to be passed like df.withColumn("renamedCountries", mapCountries($"countries",$"code")) what should  i give in the place of udf[String, String]

Comment: @minnu, Passing multiple columns into an udf will end up one resulting column e.g. if you pass ($"countries",$"code") columns then the result will be one column named `renamedCountries `.

Comment: Instead you shall try to invoke the udf for every column like `df.withColumn("renamedCountries", mapCountries($"countries")).withColumn("renamedCode", mapCountries($"code"))`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with `typedLit`, so whenever there is a change only update on the `map` on method,

```
val df  = Seq("RFRA","BRES","EAST", "RUSS").toDF("countries")

    val replaceMap = typedLit(Map("RFRA" -> "FRA",
      "BRES" -> "BRA",
      "RESP" -> "ESP",
      "RBEL" -> "BEL",
      "RGRB" -> "GBR",
      "RALL" -> "DEU",
      "MARO" -> "MAR",
      "RPOR" -> "PRT"))

    def replace(countries: Column): Column = {
      when(replaceMap($"$countries").isNotNull,replaceMap($"$countries"))
        .otherwise(lit("unknown"))
    }
    
    val res = df.withColumn("modified_countries", replace($"countries"))
    res.show(false)

+---------+------------------+
|countries|modified_countries|
+---------+------------------+
|RFRA     |FRA               |
|BRES     |BRA               |
|EAST     |unknown           |
|RUSS     |unknown           |
+---------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define it as a reusable expression :

```
def replace(c: Column): Column = {
  when(c === "RFRA", "FRA")
    .when(c === "BRES", "BRA")
    .when(c === "RESP", "ESP")
    .when(c === "RBEL", "BEL")
    // add more here
    .otherwise("unknown")
}

df
  .withColumn("contries",replace($"countries"))
  .show()
```

you can also pack the modifications inside a map and use it in this expression :

```
val replaceMap = Map("RFRA" -> "FRA",
      "BRES" -> "BRA",
      "RESP" -> "ESP",
      "RBEL" -> "BEL",
      "RGRB" -> "GBR",
      "RALL" -> "DEU",
      "MARO" -> "MAR",
      "RPOR" -> "PRT")

def replace(countries: Column): Column = {
      replaceMap.foldLeft(when(lit(false),countries)){case (acc,(k,v)) => acc.when(countries === k,v)}
        .otherwise("unknown")
  }
```